# Paypal Payment Invalid when redirecting with javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I have a problem with Paypal SDK REST, ASP.NET MVC 5 (C#) and javascript redirection.

I'm creating all the required components (ItemList, Address, Details, Amount,...) to make a Payment object for Paypal (not using credit card, so FundingInstruments are empty). After it is created, I use a View with a JavaScript Redirection to the URL Payment object has given to me. But everytime I see a 'Transaction is not valid...'

But, If I copy/Paste the URL ("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=...") to my browser MANUALLY, it works ! I'm going crazy...

Please have you got a solution ? (Find Enclosed the c# file, the payment in json format and the small html redirection component)

1. C# Payment Class

> using System;
>       using System.Collections.Generic;
>       using System.Linq;
>       using System.Web;
>       using PayPal;
>       using PayPal.Api;
>       using System.Configuration;
>       using System.Threading;
>
> ```
> namespace WizziqWebApp.Paypal
> {
>     public class PaymentService
>     {
>         public enum EPaymentMethod { Paypal, CreditCard };
>         public static readonly Dictionary<EPaymentMethod, string> PaymentMethods = new Dictionary<EPaymentMethod, string>() {
>             { EPaymentMethod.Paypal, "paypal" },
>             { EPaymentMethod.CreditCard, "credit_card" }
>         };
>
>         private OAuthTokenCredential _authToken;
>         private APIContext _api;
>
>         public Payment CreatePayment(Models.OrderModel order, EPaymentMethod paymentMethod, string cancelUrl, string returnUrl)
>         {
>             ItemList itemList = CreateItemList(order.shoppingCart);            
>             //itemList.shipping_address = (ShippingAddress) CreateDeliveryAddress(order.fullRegisterModel);            
>             Address InvoicingAddress = CreateInvoiceAddress(order.fullRegisterModel);            
>             Details details = CreatePaymentDetails(order.shoppingCart);
>             Amount amount = CreateAmount(order.shoppingCart, details);
>
>             Payer payer = null;
>             if (paymentMethod == EPaymentMethod.CreditCard)
>             {
>                 CreditCard creditCard = CreateCreditCard(InvoicingAddress);
>                 FundingInstrument fundingInstrument = CreateCreditCardFundingInstrument(creditCard);
>                 List<FundingInstrument> lst = new List<FundingInstrument>();
>                 lst.Add(fundingInstrument);
>                 payer = CreatePayerCreditCard(lst);
>             }
>             else if (paymentMethod == EPaymentMethod.Paypal)
>             {
>                 payer = CreatePayerPaypal();
>             }
>
>             var transactionList = new List<Transaction>();
>             Transaction transaction = CreateTransaction(amount, itemList, order);
>             transactionList.Add(transaction);
>
>
>             var payment = new Payment
>             {
>                 transactions = transactionList,
>                 intent = "sale",
>                 payer = payer,
>                 redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls
>                 {
>                     cancel_url = cancelUrl,
>                     return_url = returnUrl
>                 }
>             };
>
>             payment = payment.Create(this.Api);
>
>             System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"d:\devel\PaymentObject.json",
> ```
>
> `payment.ConvertToJson());`
>
> ```
>             return payment;
>         }
>
>         public Payment ConfirmPayment(string token, string payerId)
>         {
>             var paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution
>             {
>                 payer_id = payerId
>             };
>
>             var payment = new Payment { id = token };
>
>             return payment.Execute(this.Api, paymentExecution);
>         }
>
>         private ItemList CreateItemList(Models.ShoppingCart Cart)
>         {
>             ItemList PaypalItemList = new ItemList();
>             List<Item> itms = new List<Item>();
>
>             if (Cart != null)
>             {
>                 foreach (Models.ShoppingCartLine line in Cart.Lines)
>                 {
>                     Item item = new Item();
>                     item.name = line.Product.ArticleId;
>                     item.currency = line.Currency.ShortCode;
>                     item.price = line.UnitPrice.ToString("0.00", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
>                     item.quantity = Convert.ToString(line.Quantity);
>                     item.sku = line.Product.ArticleId;
>                     itms.Add(item);
>                 }
>             }
>
>             PaypalItemList.items = itms;
>             return PaypalItemList;
>         }
>
>         private Address CreateInvoiceAddress(Models.FullRegisterModel model)
>         {
>             Address Address = null;
>
>             if (model != null && model.InvoicingAddress != null)
>             {
>                 Address = new Address();
>                 Address.city = model.InvoicingAddress.City;
>                 Address.country_code = model.InvoicingAddress.Country;
>                 Address.line1 = model.InvoicingAddress.StreetAddress;
>                 Address.postal_code = model.InvoicingAddress.ZipCode;
>                 Address.state = model.InvoicingAddress.State;
>             }
>
>             return Address;
>         }
>
>         private ShippingAddress CreateDeliveryAddress(Models.FullRegisterModel model)
>         {
>             ShippingAddress Address = null;
>
>             if (model != null && model.DeliveryAddress != null)
>             {
>                 Address = new ShippingAddress();
>                 Address.city = model.DeliveryAddress.City;
>                 Address.country_code = model.DeliveryAddress.Country;
>                 Address.line1 = model.DeliveryAddress.StreetAddress;
>                 Address.postal_code = model.DeliveryAddress.ZipCode;
>                 Address.state = model.DeliveryAddress.State;
>                 Address.recipient_name = model.LastName + ", " + model.FirstName;
>             }
>
>             return Address;
>         }
>
>         private CreditCard CreateCreditCard(Address invoiceAddress) 
>         {
>             CreditCard creditCard = null;
>             {
>                 creditCard = new CreditCard();
>                 creditCard.billing_address = invoiceAddress;
>                 creditCard.cvv2 = "874";  //card cvv2 number
>                 creditCard.expire_month = 4; //card expire date
>                 creditCard.expire_year = 2020; //card expire year
>                 creditCard.first_name = "Aman";
>                 creditCard.last_name = "Thakur";
>                 creditCard.number = "4032034438655220"; //enter your credit card number here
>                 creditCard.type = "visa"; //credit card type here paypal allows 4 types
>             }
>             return creditCard;
>         }
>
>         private Details CreatePaymentDetails(Models.ShoppingCart Cart)
>         {
>             Details details = null;
>             if (Cart != null)
>             {
>                 details = new Details();
>                 details.shipping = Convert.ToString(Cart.DeliveryFee.Total);
>                 details.subtotal = Convert.ToString(Cart.GetTotal());
>                 details.tax = "0";
>             }
>             return details;
>         }
>
>         private Amount CreateAmount(Models.ShoppingCart Cart, Details details)
>         {
>             var total = Cart.GetTotal() + Cart.DeliveryFee.Total + Convert.ToDecimal(details.tax);
>
>             var amount = new Amount
>             {
>                 currency = Cart.Currency.ShortCode,
>                 details = details,
>                 total = total.ToString()
>             };
>
>             return amount;
>         }
>
>         private Transaction CreateTransaction(Amount amount, ItemList itemList, Models.OrderModel model)
>         {
>             Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
>             if (amount != null && itemList != null)
>             {
>                 transaction.amount = amount;
>                 transaction.description = "WIZZIQ products";
>                 transaction.invoice_number = Convert.ToString(model.OrderNumber);
>                 transaction.item_list = itemList;
>                 //transaction.notify_url = "";
>                 //transaction.order_url = "";
>             }
>             return transaction;
>         }
>
>         private FundingInstrument CreateCreditCardFundingInstrument(CreditCard creditCard)
>         {
>             return new FundingInstrument()
>             {
>                 credit_card = creditCard
>             };
>         }
>
>         private Payer CreatePayerCreditCard(List<FundingInstrument> listFundingInstruments)
>         {
>             Payer payer = new Payer();
>             if (listFundingInstruments != null)
>             {
>                 payer.funding_instruments = listFundingInstruments;
>                 payer.payment_method = PaymentMethods[EPaymentMethod.CreditCard];
>             }
>             return payer;
>         }
>
>         private Payer CreatePayerPaypal()
>         {
>             Payer payer = new Payer();
>             payer.payment_method = PaymentMethods[EPaymentMethod.Paypal];
>             return payer;
>         }
>
>         private OAuthTokenCredential ApiAccessToken
>         {
>             get
>             {
>                 if (this._authToken != null)
>                 {
>                     return this._authToken;
>                 }
>
>                 var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"];
>                 var secretToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secretToken"];
>                 var config = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "mode", "sandbox" } };
>
>                 this._authToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(clientId, secretToken, config);
>
>                 return this._authToken;
>             }
>         }
>
>         private APIContext Api
>         {
>             get
>             {
>                 return this._api ?? (this._api = new APIContext(this.ApiAccessToken.GetAccessToken()));
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

2. HTML Redirection

> ```
> @{
>     ViewBag.Title = "_Redirect";
>     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layout/_LayoutEmpty.cshtml";
> }
>
> <div class="jumbotron">
>     <div class="container">
>         <h1>Please wait...</h1>
>         <p>        
>             <div class="popover-content">                
>                     <div class="loading-circle"></div>
>                     <div class="loading-circle1"></div>
>                     <div class="small-title clr-wizziq text-center"><span>While redirecting to Paypal...</span></div>
>
>             </div>
>         </p>
>     </div>
> </div>
>
> <script>
>     setTimeout(function () {
>         var url = '@ViewBag.RedirectUrl';
>         alert('Redirect to: ' + url);
>         window.location.href = url;
>     }, 1000);
> </script>
> ```

3. JSON Payment

> ```
> {  
>    "id":"PAY-14N977666S5313604KWP4CGQ",
>    "intent":"sale",
>    "payer":{  
>       "payment_method":"paypal",
>       "payer_info":{  
>          "shipping_address":{  
>
>          }
>       }
>    },
>    "transactions":[  
>       {  
>          "related_resources":[  
>
>          ],
>          "amount":{  
>             "currency":"EUR",
>             "total":"18033.45",
>             "details":{  
>                "subtotal":"18033.45"
>             }
>          },
>          "description":"WIZZIQ products",
>          "invoice_number":"4",
>          "item_list":{  
>             "items":[  
>                {  
>                   "quantity":"1",
>                   "name":"IQREPAIRKIT",
>                   "price":"1500.00",
>                   "currency":"EUR",
>                   "sku":"IQREPAIRKIT"
>                },
>                {  
>                   "quantity":"3",
>                   "name":"IQBUR010",
>                   "price":"9.20",
>                   "currency":"EUR",
>                   "sku":"IQBUR010"
>                },
>                {  
>                   "quantity":"1",
>                   "name":"IQBUR016",
>                   "price":"9.20",
>                   "currency":"EUR",
>                   "sku":"IQBUR016"
>                },
>                {  
>                   "quantity":"250",
>                   "name":"IQREP20INJ",
>                   "price":"49.90",
>                   "currency":"EUR",
>                   "sku":"IQREP20INJ"
>                },
>                {  
>                   "quantity":"1",
>                   "name":"IQPOLISH",
>                   "price":"3.75",
>                   "currency":"EUR",
>                   "sku":"IQPOLISH"
>                },
>                {  
>                   "quantity":"2",
>                   "name":"IQTRANSFO",
>                   "price":"8.95",
>                   "currency":"EUR",
>                   "sku":"IQTRANSFO"
>                },
>                {  
>                   "quantity":"5",
>                   "name":"IQSTARTERKIT",
>                   "price":"800.00",
>                   "currency":"EUR",
>                   "sku":"IQSTARTERKIT"
>                }
>             ]
>          }
>       }
>    ],
>    "state":"created",
>    "create_time":"2015-07-10T12:56:58Z",
>    "update_time":"2015-07-10T12:56:58Z",
>    "links":[  
>       {  
>          "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-14N977666S5313604KWP4CGQ",
>          "rel":"self",
>          "method":"GET"
>       },
>       {  
>          "href":"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-4HC32806NW4529238",
>          "rel":"approval_url",
>          "method":"REDIRECT"
>       },
>       {  
>          "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-14N977666S5313604KWP4CGQ/execute",
>          "rel":"execute",
>          "method":"POST"
>       }
>    ]
> }
> ```

Thank you very much ! I'm really stuck...

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here's how I fixed it:

Ok, that was my fault, the redirection was not what I expected to be... To correct it, don't forget to put your URL from RAZOR in RAW mode :).

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
        var url = '**@Html.Raw(Model.Url)**';
        alert('Redirect to: ' + url);
        window.location.href = url;
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Anyway, thanks to the Paypal team for trying to help but too late :)